# MySQL Consecutive Numbers questions: the order of count query matters?

Tags: mysql, rank

I am hitting a puzzle when solving this question:

```
Write a SQL query to find all numbers that appear at least three times consecutively.

+----+-----+
| Id | Num |
+----+-----+
| 1  |  1  |
| 2  |  1  |
| 3  |  1  |
| 4  |  2  |
| 5  |  1  |
| 6  |  2  |
| 7  |  2  |
```

For example, given the above Logs table, 1 is the only number that appears consecutively for at least three times.

```
+-----------------+
| ConsecutiveNums |
+-----------------+
| 1               |
+-----------------+
```

My first solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Num As ConsecutiveNums
FROM (
    SELECT 
    ID, 
    Num,
    @PreNum:=Num as PreNum,
    @Count:=IF(@PreNum=Num, @Count+1,1) AS Count

    FROM Logs,
    (SELECT @PreNum:=0,@Count:=1) x

    ) y
where y.Count>=3;
```

The code above will return the incorrect results:

```
{"headers":["ConsecutiveNums"],"values":[[1],[2]]}
```

However, if I move the line "@Count:=IF(@PreNum=Num, @Count+1,1) AS Count," above "@PreNum:=Num as PreNum", it will generate the expected results.  Any reason why the order of these 2 lines matter?  Thank you!

```
SELECT DISTINCT Num As ConsecutiveNums
FROM (
    SELECT 
    ID, 
    Num,
    @Count:=IF(@PreNum=Num, @Count+1,1) AS Count,
    @PreNum:=Num as PreNum


    FROM Logs,
    (SELECT @PreNum:=0,@Count:=1) x

    ) y
where y.Count>=3;
```

Results:

```
{"headers":["ConsecutiveNums"],"values":[[1]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand now:

```
@Count:=IF(@PreNum=Num, @Count+1,1) AS Count,
@PreNum:=Num as PreNum
```

If we leave @Count above "@PreNum:=Num as PreNum" , it means the If logic is still examing the @PreNum that hasn't been re-assigned in "@PreNum:=Num as PreNum".